# On the solution of a matrix optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-equations, control-theory

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix with eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that $\mathrm{Re}(\lambda_i)<0$. Moreover, let $\succeq$ denote the standard partial order in the cone of positive definite matrices.

Consider the following maximization problem
\begin{align}\label{eq:opt}\tag{$\ast$}
M=\sup_{P,X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}} \quad & \mathrm{tr}(XP^{-1})\\
\text{s.t.} \quad & AP+(AP)^\top=-X \\
& X=X^\top \succeq 0 \\
& \mathrm{tr}(X)=1 \\
& P=P^\top \succeq 0.
\end{align}

Notice that we can rewrite \eqref{eq:opt} as
\begin{align}
M&=\sup_{\substack{X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\\ X=X^\top\succeq 0,\ \mathrm{tr}(X)=1}} -\mathrm{tr}((AP+PA^\top)P^{-1})=-2\mathrm{tr}(A).
\end{align}

> **My question.** If the cost function $\mathrm{tr}(XP^{-1})$ in \eqref{eq:opt} is replaced by $\mathrm{tr}(X(\alpha I+ P)^{-1})$, with $\alpha>0$, is it true that 
>   $$
> M= \frac{1}{\alpha-\frac{1}{2\mathrm{tr}(A)}} \ \ \ ?
> $$

From an extensive amount of numerical simulations it seems that answer to my latter question is in the affirmative. However, after spending a lot of time thinking about this, I couldn't prove it. So, any help is really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What does $X>0$ mean? Could you properly add constraints to (*) and add P as an optimization variable?

Comment: @LinAlg $X>0$ means that $X$ is positive definite. I’ve explicitly added the constraints to the problem.

Comment: can you use the well known result that $(I+P)^{-1} = I + P + P^2 + P^3 + \ldots$?

Comment: @LinAlg Yes, I've thought about this fact, but I don't see how this can be helpful...